# Can a commercial cargo aircraft be converted into a commercial passenger aircraft, and vice versa?

Tags: cabin-design

Just saw a video in a news, a military cargo plane carrying people stranded in some country. The seats were like in a commercial airliner. This led me to ask the question.

Would it be possible to see some examples where it was done, along with the procedure?

Comment: This paper details the general procedure for a "dedicated passenger" to "dedicated freighter" conversion.  http://www.icas.org/ICAS_ARCHIVE/ICAS2014/data/papers/2014_0001_paper.pdf

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There are such a thing as "Quick Change" aircraft, allowing entire 'pallets' of chairs to be exchanged for cargo.

[image: pic]<sup>Image courtesy of canalblog.com</sup>

[image: qc]<sup>Image courtesy of airliner.net</sup>

[Nice film](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N3zb3Re4sjc) to show the process.

Military transport aircraft can also be fitted out with stretchers or seats, or whatever other combo of stuff you want. To the best of my understanding these lock in like any other cargo pallet in the floor. They are less concerned with aesthetics and more with practicality:

[image: military]<sup>Image courtesy the DOD via Wikimedia</sup>

[image: seats]
<sup>Image courtesy of aarcorp.com</sup>

Comment: It should be noted, that for military it's the _standard_ way of doing things. Air forces generally don't have dedicated planes for carrying people, so whenever they need to move troops, and they do often, they always use these removable seats (unless they charter civilian plane).

Comment: Excellent explanation and illustration

Comment: I am missing a source stating how many of these Quick-Change aircraft are available at different fleet operators. I doubt that FedEx could convert any single of its planes, but that's just a gut feeling...

Comment: @Alexander few quick-change planes exist, mostly because I think it's difficult to get an efficient mixed service. [Pemco](http://pemcoair.com/conversions/) states that you can only get in 8 instead of 9 pallets and it takes 20-30 minutes to get the seats in and out. I can't find any number built either....

Comment: @Alexander : But Fed-Ex planes don't have windows. Or do they?

Comment: @Firee They would never have interest in going into passenger ops for starters. The side windows are plugged or they are dedicated freighters without them at all...

Comment: The commercial type is called a [combi aircraft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combi_aircraft).

Comment: ...and sooner or later the seats are all located at the wrong airport!

Comment: It should be noted that the military aircraft pictured has fold-out seats along the sides. Those seats are most likely permanent, while the ones in the middle are just ordinary freight.

Comment: @fooot: No, a quick-change is an airplane that can carry passengers _or_ freight.  A combi carries passengers _and_ freight.

Answer (score 25):

It applies to helicopters too.

When on holiday in the West Indies, one of the locations offered helicopter rides.  If anyone booked one, they contacted the local freight helicopter company who put the seats back into the helicopter, then they flew you round the bay, then took the seats out again to continue their bread-and-butter freight work.

The pilot told us helicopters come with seats, they took them out and put them in the shed.  They formed the company to shift building materials to construction sites.  One day a man approached them and asked if they could do sight-seeing rides for tourists.  They checked the seats were still in the shed and said "of course".

Answer (score 6):

I used to fly a Twin Otter aircraft that was used in the UK to carry cargo (newspapers) at night and passengers in the day. The seats were carried in the rear of the aircraft and the pilot who flew it at night put the seats in before he went home. No certification was needed as there were no modifications.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. But with any modifications, the airplane will need to get re-certified by the authorities (FAA in the US) and approved, because it would have sustained modification to its structure.

Comment: This is only for massive total conversion from a dedicated commercial passenger configuration to dedicated freighter configuration - one where doors are changed, flight controls and electronics moved/reprogrammed, major interior restructuring is undertaken, etc.  For craft that are dual-purpose with simple removable seats (quick change) there is no need to re-certify.

Comment: Good points by both of you