# Why do some airports put 2 jetbridges on one aircraft?

Tags: commercial-aviation, airline-operations, airport, ground-operations

At a gate in Denver Int'l there is a United plane with 2 jetbridges.
[image: united777]

Why do some airports put 2 jetbridges on a plane? Is it necessary?

Comment: It is actually very common to put multiple jetbridges on wide-bodies. The A380 uses 3.

Comment: [Some actually have three for some planes](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/13901/1696)

Comment: Why do you assume that they _have to_?

Comment: Note that for instance EasyJet in Prague (PRG) uses a jet bridge **plus** it makes the passengers seated at the back of the place to go down on the tarmac and up by standard stairs. I believe this significantly reduces the boarding time whence the airport tax, which is quite large in PRG.

Comment: @yo' is the tax really time-dependent? Normally easyjet etc. want to minimise the turnaround time for their own operational reasons rather than anything external.

Comment: @ChrisH Honestly, I don't know,it was just an assumption. Of course, the operational costs could be an argument as well.

Comment: Look at the size of that aircraft and guess why! Who wants to keep the gate busy when they can utilize two bridges to transfer people faster than one on big aircraft

Comment: **Confusing question** ... They hardly "HAVE TO" ..... it's just much, much better.  You may as well ask "why do some airports 'have to' use bridges rather than just a bus and steps.

Comment: @kepler22b I don't understand. The title used to be "why do they do it?" and the question used to be "why do they _have to_ do it?" You get a bunch of comments saying that they don't _have to_ do it so the real question is just "why do they do it?" But then you edit the title so it includes the incorrect "have to", rather than editing the body to remove it. IDGI.

Comment: Because they can.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So that economy class passengers can also see at least one of the higher classes (when they exit) and wish they booked that!  :-/ Trust me you sure will wish that and that someday can mean more `$` for the airline

[image]
Source: Original picture was taken from this very question

Joking aside I have seen it happen on many airlines. The people on left Aisle go out from the first one and people on the right aisle take the longer route to exit from the gate that's closer to cockpit.

Primary reason must be to transfer people faster to make the jet available for crew as soon as possible specially after a landing when the jet has to fly again in an hour.

Comment: This answer is inaccurate or, at least, incomplete. I've never seen dual jet bridges used in the way described here. On all occasions that I've boarded a plane that had two jetbridges attached, all economy passengers went through the rear jetbridge, presumably to avoid disturbing the people in the fancy seats by having half a planeload of people trog past them.

Comment: So if you have never seen that happen that means that is inaccurate? I have recently seen it happen twice, once at KUL and once at BKK. And those fancy seats people offload before not so fancy ones do. Both on TG.

Comment: @DavidRicherby write your own answer if you think this one is inaccurate.

Comment: @HankyPanky I said "inaccurate or, at least, incomplete". There are many occasions on which dual jetbridges are used but are not used in the way you describe.

Comment: @kepler22b There are plenty of answers that already cover this.

Comment: But if you are really annoyed by this answer just make your own answer correcting this one. Because first you said that the title was wrong, then that the answer is inaccurate, what else comes next?

Answer (score 19):

It is not strictly necessary. But it is done in order to save time.

- More points of passenger loading leads to faster loading, potentially reducing delays, airport charges, etc.
- In some cases, there is a separate jet bridge for first/business class.
- For large aircraft like A380 etc, is quite common to use multiple jet bridges, as use of a single one may lead to quite long loading time.

Comment: Also, some planes have more than one floor for passengers and they might not want everyone to go through the narrow stairs.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk exactly; not a big deal for 747 (though you don't want your upper floor/class passengers to have to climb) with it's handful of seats on the upper deck, but in the 380...

Answer (score 9):

The reason they use 2 or sometimes even 3 (A380) for wide-body aircraft (I have seen 2 on a B757, but that is rare) is because the more entrances to facilitate faster boarding and unloading passengers from the airplane. It saves much more time than loading the plane from one jetbridge and in the case of the A380, there are 2 full wide-body decks to fill. Passengers also like getting on and getting off the plane quicker as well.

Interesting that there is [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20098/how-many-jetways-are-used-when-boarding-a-boeing-777-in-sfo) similar question on travel.se

Comment: Believe it or not, a decade ago, Southwest experimented with using two jet bridges for boarding 737's at the Albany NY airport.  It really did make boarding faster but I haven't seen done recently.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Aeroalias' answer, some airports adopt a Multi Aircraft(Apron) Ramp System.

The gate may be used by multiple small or a single large aircraft. It allows airport planners to make their gates more flexible and efficient. In such a case two or more jet bridges are needed for a single gate.

Some of the busiest airports including Beijing Capital, London Heathrow and New York JFK have already adopted such a system.

More details can see this [article](http://www.airportsinternational.com/2013/02/manoeuvres-on-mars/13873).